# Scaling a matrix such that diagonal elements are $1$

Tags: matrices

How can we scale a given matrix such that all the diagonal elements are equal to $1$. In particular what operations should be performed to obtain this kind of matrix.

Suppose there is a matrix like

\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 1 & 4\\
3 & 2 & 2 & 4\\
1 & 2 & 7 & 7\\
4 & 4 & 7 & 7\end{pmatrix}

I want to scale this matrix such that all diagonal elements are equal to $1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "scale" a matrix? Usually scaling a matrix means multiplying by a scalar: e.g., from matrix $M$ and scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, form the matrix $\lambda M$. If this is what you mean, then there is no scalar you can multiply by to get all the diagonal elements to be $1$, unless they are already all equal.

Comment: I think he means reduced row echelon form

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you multiply an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ on the left by a diagonal $m\times m$ matrix $D$, each row of $A$ is scaled by the corresponding nonzero entry in $D$.  Try it for $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ and you will see why.

Now you can work backwards: what $D$ will scale the rows of $A$ to make its diagonal terms equal to $1$?